# Erlang string:to_integer/1 failing to parse valid string

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I'm trying to read a text file that contains a integer represented in ASCII (for example, "2446") and parse that into an integer in my Erlang/OTP program. `string:to_integer/1` always returns `{error, no_integer}` when I try to parse `"1"`. Perhaps I made a beginner's mistake. What am I doing wrong? Here's the relevant code, where I try to set `Index` to the integer:

```
Index = case file:read_file(Indexpath) of
        {ok, Binary} ->
            Index2 = case string:to_integer(io_lib:format("~s", [Binary])) of
                {error, Reason} ->
                    io:format("to_integer error from input ~s: ~s~n", [Binary, Reason]),
                    0;
                {Index3, _} -> Index3
            end,
            Index2;
        {error, _} ->
            Index2 = 0,
            ok = file:write_file(Indexpath, io_lib:format("~B", [Index2+1])),
            Index2;
        _ ->
            io:format("read_file case didn't match!~n", []),
            -1
    end,
```

What gets printed to the console when I run this: `to_integer error from input 1: no_integer`
Clearly, the input is the string "1", so I don't understand why this happens. If I do a little test case,

```
Indexstr = "4", string:to_integer(Indexstr).
```

that returns {4, []} as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `io_lib:format/2` returns iolist (similar to deep list) instead of flat one. [You can find iolist definition here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html).
Moreover, in new versions of erlang (starting from R16) you can use function `erlang:binary_to_integer/1' to avoid intermediate conversions.

Comment: Thanks, this is a more thorough answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer as I was typing the question. I replaced

```
string:to_integer(io_lib:format("~s", [Binary]))
```

with

```
string:to_integer(binary_to_list(Binary))
```